# MySQL trigger issue with if clause

Tags: mysql

I'have a problem trying to create a trigger. I have table_1 and table_2, the update event on table_1 should update a row in table_2 identified using the where clause:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_table_2` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   IF table_1.key=0 THEN
      UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.value='10' WHERE table_2.key='2';   
   END IF;

END
```

What's my problem?! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a trigger, you should use the `old` and `new` keywords to reference the record that has been updated (the old values and new ones respectively).

In your case, you should do :

```
   IF new.key=0 THEN
      UPDATE table_2 SET table_2.value='10' WHERE table_2.key='2';   
   END IF;
```

Comment: Well, I tried but it did not work! Now I tried again and it works!!
So thanks!

Comment: Yes but in some minutes I will add some information because now I have another problem!

Comment: You may want to create a different question. This one had a very specific problem. It is useful for future users with the same problem. But if it is related, you can link to this question in your new one.